# TypeError on Remix for BSC Contract

Tags: solidity, remix, bep20

I have this error "TypeError: Return argument type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) address payable. --> Driven.sol:233:16: | 233 | return msg.sender; | ^^^^^^^^^^"

for the following function

```
abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address payable) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes memory) {
        this; // silence state mutability warning without generating bytecode - see https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2691
        return msg.data;
    }
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Solidity 0.8, `msg.sender` is not `payable` anymore. You need to cast it to `payable` first.

```
function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address payable) {
    return payable(msg.sender); // added payable
}
```

Or you can return just `address` (not payable):

```
function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {  // removed payable
    return msg.sender;
}
```

Comment: I have one more warning (not an error):

Warning: Visibility for constructor is ignored. If you want the contract to be non-deployable, making it "abstract" is sufficient. --> Driven.sol:732:5: | 732 | constructor () public { | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

for this function

Comment: constructor () public {
        _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;
        IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F);
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())
            .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());
        uniswapV2Router = _uniswapV2Router;
        _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
        emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotal);
    }

Comment: @Paul-ConstantinSocarde The constructor is executed **only** during the deployment, and can't be called later, so it makes sense that the visibility is ignored. You can remove the `public` modifier from the constructor.

Comment: Also if the interface of the contract is IERC20, can I list it on BSC? Or should be BEP20?

Comment: I ask that because I saw that MoonPirate's contract is using IERC20 and the token is tradeable on PancakeSwap (BEP20 platform)

Comment: How you actually name the interface, is unrelated. BEP20 standard extends the ERC20 ([source](https://academy.binance.com/en/glossary/bep-20)), and for the code part, you just need to follow the [ERC20](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md).